# Leafletjs + Vue.js: Too few tiles are requested

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

My map is not loading correctly. It's like a puzzle which hasn't been finished. There are white gaps where tiles should have been placed but there are missing.

The problem is, that only 6 images have been requested (GET-Request) but there should be more.

[Image of the requested tiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCjJr.png)

I'm importing leafletjs as a npm package

`import leaflet from 'leaflet'`

and this is my code

```
    const map = leaflet
      .map('map')
      .setView([51.509865, -0.118092], 13)

    leaflet.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map)
```

this is my HTML structure

```
  <div
    id="map"
    class="col-9 pl-0 pr-0">
  </div>
```

I also gave the div container a `height` of `400px` and a `width` of `600px`

[Image of the rendered map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwwEn.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the `leaflet.css` file too. So, if you have `main.scss` just import the next line

```
@import "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
```

or in your `index.html` add a `script` tag like this

```
<style src='node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay easy enough: I had to import the leaflet styles too to make this work properly.

Inside my component, I embedded those styles via the style tag

```
<style src='leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'></style>
```